# Read data during migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have the following scenario:

Module A & B have their settings stored in an XML file. Module C has its settings stored in the DB (table with one row).  Now I would like to move the settings from Module C to the XML file where A & B store their respective settings.

When I delete the `SettingsC` entity in the settings table will be deleted on the next migration.

**Is there a way to read the tables content during that migration** and write it to the XML file before the table is deleted?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public partial class DropModuleCSettings : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        // here I would like to read the content of "dbo.SettingsC"
        DropTable("dbo.SettingsC");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the timing of "When" to get the data out of the ModuleC Database table but you are probably going to be looking at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2010/05/11/export-sql-table-records-to-xml-form.aspx

Basically:

```
SELECT * FROM SettingsC FOR XML AUTO
```

This will give you the contents of your table in an XML file.

To retrieve this information do something along the lines of:

```
using (SqlConnection oCn = new SqlConnection())
{
    oCn.ConnectionString = @"server=sql-server\cos;integrated security=SSPI;database=daas5";
    oCn.Open();

    // Create a SQL command object.
    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SettingsC FOR XML AUTO";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, oCn);
    //Read you query into an XmlReader
    XmlReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();        
}
```

Once you have that, you can easily load this into an XDocument

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

or an XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(reader);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but how could I execute this during my migration is the main problem I have. The `Sql("...")` function does not return any data...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include how to get the data out of SQL as an XmlDocument.

Comment: Thanks. Did not think of using a "separte SQL-Connection" and was hoping I could use the EF-Connection, but I will try that and report back...

Comment: You can probably reuse your existing connection and just create a new command, upon which you call ExecuteXmlReader